# OpenGL drawing models using Assimp

Tags: model, assimp

I'm currently learning OpenGL with a huge help from www.learnopengl.com.
I'm currently stuck at Model tutorial inside Model loading overlap. Problem is that I don't get a correct result after finishing this tutorial. The result I get is shown here:

My model
[image]

It's far from the result I expected:
[image]

I have pretty much the same code for model, mesh classes and shaders, and can't figure why do I get the result. I debugged shaders by checking tex coordinates and sampler texture.
Could that be problem with assimp library itself? If not, what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How did you open images?
Try to change in glTexImage2D `GL_RGB` to `GL_RGBA`.
Good luck.